# How can I convert float to integer in Java

Tags: java, casting, integer, type-conversion

I need to convert a float number into an integer.

Can Java automatically convert float number into integers? If so, do normal rounding rules apply (e.g. 3.4 gets converted to 3, but 3.6 gets converted to 4)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in Math library function `round(float a)` it's round the float to the nearest whole number.

```
int val = Math.round(3.6); \\ val = 4
int val2 = Math.round(3.4); \\ val2 = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit dirty but it works:

```
double a=3.6;
int b = (int) (a + 0.5);
```

See the result [here](https://ideone.com/EbskNG)

Comment: what's the motivation behind the downvoting?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your solution wouldn't even compile, the result of `(int) a + 0.5` is of type double, which can't be assinged to an `int` have a try

Comment: anyone who knows java with a bit of good sense would realise where the compilation error was before my edit, and would get the logic behind my answer. However, I have edited it and provided a link that shows it working and compiling

Answer (score 0):

Math.round(3.6) would do that for you.